# Trouble in Understanding an Inequality in Rudin RCA 11.16

Tags: inequality

I am dealing with the following inequality:
$$|u_r(e^{i\theta})|^p\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f(t)|^pP_r(\theta-t)dt,$$
where $1\le p\le\infty$, $0\le r<1$, $P_r$ the Poisson kernel,
$$u_r(e^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)P_r(\theta-t)dt$$
and $f(t)\in L^p(T)$.

I can't figure out how this inequality is obtained. Here are my attempts:

> Consider Jensen's Inequality. Then
> $$
> \left| u_r\left( e^{i\theta} \right) \right|^p=\left| \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f\left( t \right) P_r\left( \theta -t \right) \frac{dt}{2\pi}} \right|^p\le \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left| f\left( t \right) \right|^p\cdot \left| P_r\left( \theta -t \right) \right|^p\frac{dt}{2\pi}}\overset{?}{\le}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left| f\left( t \right) \right|^p\cdot P_r\left( \theta -t \right) \frac{dt}{2\pi}}.
> $$
> I can't convince me that the final step is true. Indeed there are segments that $P_r$ is larger than $1$.

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

**To avoid possible typos (or misunderstandings), I will put the image of the relevent materials on the book below:**
[image]
[image]
where 11.5(3) is the elementrary fact that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(t)dt=1.$$

Comment: I doubt it's true as written, especially taking $p=\infty$

Comment: I made an edit to put the image of the relevent materials from the book.

Comment: Simple application of Jensen's inequality. $t^{p}$ is convex for $p \ge 1$.

Comment: Rudin uses this inequlaity only for $1\le p<\infty$. Proof of (1) for $p=\infty$ is entirely trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Rudin formulates Jensen's inequality for an arbitrary probability space, and he is applying it in this instance not to the normalized Lebesgue measure $\frac{1}{2\pi} \, dt$ on $\mathbb{T}$, but to the probability measure $\frac{1}{2\pi} P_r(\theta - t) \, dt$ on $\mathbb{T}$ (here $r$ and $\theta$ are fixed for purposes of applying the inequality).  The symbolic effect is that one does not need to include $P_r(\theta - t)$ in what is "raised to the $p$" inside the integral, as one would if one were applying Jensen's inequality to the normalized Lebesgue measure.  The fact that the $p$th power of the modulus of the right hand side of Rudin's equation (3) is at most the right hand side of Rudin's equation (4) is thus (as a commenter to the original post stated but did not explain) a fairly literal consequence of Jensen's inequality (again, not in $(\mathbb{T}, \frac{1}{2\pi} \, dt)$ but in this other probability space).  Rudin's passing reference to Hölder's inequality is similar: he means Hölder's inequality in the measure space $(\mathbb{T}, \frac{1}{2\pi} P_r(\theta - t) \, dt)$.

Your excerpt includes Rudin's remark that his readers should "note" that his formula 11.5(3) was "used twice" in an argument that does not expressly refer to this formula anywhere.  (Some authors use textbook ink to say *when and where* they use things; this alternative use of ink is *classic* Rudin.)  The fact that $\frac{1}{2\pi} P_r(\theta - t) \, dt$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{T}$ implicates at least one use of formula 11.5(3).  More explicitly, the pointwise nonnegativity of $t \mapsto P_r(\theta - t)$ on $\mathbb{T}$, which Rudin states immediately after his formula 11.5(3), tells us that $\frac{1}{2\pi} P_r(\theta - t) \, dt$ is what Rudin elsewhere calls a "positive" measure on $\mathbb{T}$ (and not e.g. the "signed" or "complex" measure that might result from considering $h(t) \, dt$ for a more general real- or complex-valued function $h$ on $\mathbb{T}$); then Rudin's formula 11.5(3) tells us that this measure is a *probability* measure on $\mathbb{T}$, and thus a measure capable of being fed directly into his formulation of Jensen's inequality.

At first glance, it may be surprising that when $(X, d\mu)$ is a probability space and $h$ is a function such that $(X, h \, d\mu)$ is also a probability space, one can sometimes obtain "more" or at least "different" "information" out of applying Jensen's inequality in $(X, h \, d\mu)$ instead of $(X, d\mu)$.  Analysis is full of situations where changes of this sort have the effect of canceling out in some essential way and not producing anything new, but this is not one of them.  The ability to make judicious choice of measure space is actually a big part of what gives Jensen's inequality (and other inequalities in abstract measure spaces) its power.